# How to make dashboard page in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to create this type dashboard [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQeCm.png) but not able to work. How can we make this type style.

I try to make this type dashboard page in my code but it's not work. Anybody please help me out. And check my code below.

My js code

```
return (
    <div className="dashboard">
      <div className="dashboard__container">
        Logged in as
        <div>{name}</div>
        <div>{user?.email}</div>
        <button className="dashboard__btn" onClick={logout}>
          Logout
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And my css code

```
.dashboard {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3e295a40;
}

.dashboard__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #15b88357;
  padding: 1em 20px 1em 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dashboard__btn {
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #402958;
}

.center {   text-align: center; }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Anyone help me out

Comment: Anyone idea how can we do that

Comment: Can you able to make it using html and css/bootstrap ?

Comment: @Alok how can we do that using reactjs bootstrap in js file and css file any idea

Comment: I am using reactjs not simple html I try to make css bootstrap in reactjs  but not able to do

Comment: First make it using simple HTML and css/bootstrap then try to do in reactjs.

Comment: If you are not going to use bootstrap script which is helful in drop down then you can add link to the bootstrap.css in index.html page present in your /public directory. Or if you have to dropdowns and other interactive features of bootstrap then try to use bootrap package from npm.

Comment: Ohk thanks but i try to do it's not work

Comment: @Alok if possible can we show me some example in any online editor like sandox, codepen, js fiddle etc it's very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I am using bootstrap for "css only" to design my website generally. Here is how I do it.

/public/index.html

You can see that I have linked to my local bootstrap css file inside head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      if(window.screen.height < window.screen.width) {
        window.stop()
        // window.location = "https://google.com"
      }
    </script>
    <script src="init.js" ></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/style.css" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #efefef">
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

/src/App.js
I tried to demonstrate how I used css of bootstrap inside my reactjs component. You can also use `className`. Also take care while adding inline style. It must be object.

```
const Main = () => {
  return(
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style={{width:"100vw", height:"100vh"}}>
      <div>1</div>
      <div class="flex-grow-1">2</div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn-primary p-2">Abe !</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main;
```

If you get any error. Search for the error and try to resolve with help of google. Those error are common and can be easily fixed. You will learn alot from those errors.